# Is it possible to resolve a URL in an injected class constructor using Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, constructor-injection

I have a service class that is being used in an ASP.Net MVC 5 web application and in a console application also. Let's call it MyService. When a MyService object is being instantiated by Ninject to be passed to a controller in a web context, I would like a URL to be resolved using something like this

```
url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "Emailer" });
```

When MyService is being instantiated by my console app (using Ninject also, but in a non-web context), I would like it to take the url from AppSettings like this:

```
url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailerUrl"];
```

Is this feasible? I think it might be using WithConstructorArgument() with the proper arguments in NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) when creating the binding, but I don't know how exactly.

My guess is that the MyService constructor would have to know about the controller class in which it is being injected and be able to call methods from that controller. If no controller class is known, then it would use the app settings.

Of course, I could also set the url parameter within each controller constructor being passed a MyService object, and elsewhere in the console app, but I would prefer not to worry about setting this attribute every time a MyService object is instantiated.

Comment: Do i understand correctly, that the URL is depending on the controller `MyService` is injected into? When is `MyService` not directly injected into a controller?

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit When MyService is being injected into a controller, then that controller is able to resolve the Emailer URL, since the EmailerController is part of the web application itself. However, when it is being injected into the console app, there is no way to resolve the URL using routing, so it will have to be defined in the app settings. Of course, it could always be taken from the app settings, but it would be less practical because the address changes when I am debugging with the VS debugger, or simply calling the web site locally using localhost. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Not entirely: When running as console ap, the MyService is not being injected into a controller? Where does the app settings entry name (AppSettings["EmailerUrl"]) come from then? Constant?

Answer (score 1):

So let's start with:

```
public interface IUrl
{
    Url Url { get; } 
}

internal class ControllerBasedUrl : IUrl
{
    public ControllerBasedUrl(string controllerName)
    {
        this.Url = null; // implement
    }

    public Url Url { get; private set; }
}

internal class AppConfigBasedUrl : IUrl
{
    public AppConfigBasedUrl()
    {
        this.Url = null; // implement
    }

    public Url Url { get; private set; }
}
```

There's multiple approaches you can use:

a) make it known to the application whether you're running in a web application or console application, and then use a conditional binding:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

if (runningInConsoleApplication)
{
    kernel.Bind<IUrl>().To<AppConfigBasedUrl>();
}
else
{
    kernel.Bind<IUrl>().ToMethod(ctx =>
    {
        IRequest controllerRequest = ctx.Request.TraverseRequestChainAndFindMatch(x => x.Target.Name.EndsWith("Controller"));
        return new ControllerBasedUrl(controllerRequest.Target.Type.Name);
    });
}
```

b) make the binding for url conditional on whether it is injected into controller or not:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Bind<IUrl>().ToMethod(ctx =>
{
    IRequest controllerRequest = ctx.Request.TraverseRequestChainAndFindMatch(x => x.Target.Name.EndsWith("Controller"));
    if (controllerRequest != null)
    {
        return new ControllerBasedUrl(controllerRequest.Target.Type.Name);
    }

    return new AppConfigBasedUrl();
});
```

---

both using this extension:

```
public static class RequestExtensions
{
    public static IRequest TraverseRequestChainAndFindMatch(this IRequest request, Func<IRequest, bool> matcher)
    {
        if (matcher(request))
        {
            return request;
        }

        if (request.ParentRequest != null)
        {
            return request.ParentRequest.TraverseRequestChainAndFindMatch(matcher);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```